# How do nested dosync calls behave?

Tags: clojure, stm

What happens when you create nested dosync calls? Will sub-transactions be completed in the parent scope? Are these sub-transactions reversible if the parent transaction fails?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you mean syntactic nesting, then the answer is **it depends on whether the inner `dosync` will run on the same thread as the outer one**.

In Clojure, whenever a `dosync` block is entered, a new transaction is started *if one hasn't been running already on this thread*. This means that while execution stays on a single thread, inner transactions can be said to be subsumed by outer transactions; however if a `dosync` occupies a position syntactically nested within another `dosync`, but happens to be launched on a new thread, it will have a new transaction to itself.

An example which (hopefully) illustrates what happens:

```
user> (def r (ref 0))
#'user/r
user> (dosync (future (dosync (Thread/sleep 50) (println :foo) (alter r inc)))
              (println :bar)
              (alter r inc))
:bar
:foo
:foo
1
user> @r
2
```

The "inner" transaction retries after printing `:foo`; the "outer" transaction never needs to restart. (Note that after this happens, `r`'s history chain is grown, so if the "large" `dosync` form were evaluated for a second time, the inner `dosync` would not retry. It still wouldn't be merged into the outer one, of course.)

Incidentally, Mark Volkmann has written a fantastic article on Clojure's [Software Transactional Memory](http://java.ociweb.com/mark/stm/article.html); it's highly recommended reading for anyone interested in gaining solid insight into details of this sort.

Comment: Why the "syntactically" qualifier? And what does syntactically mean? I am a common lisper and I am accustomed to "lexically", as in closing over variables that are lexically visible: (let ((x 42)) (lambda () x)) vs dynamically (ie, bound in the call stack somewhere).