# What category of Transactional Model does the Clojure STM fall into?

Tags: clojure, transactions, stm

I'm familiar with [Database transactions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction), and spent lots of timing tuning [isolation levels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_(database_systems)).  I have never implemented my own transactional model in code.

I've read through [the source code](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/LockingTransaction.java) for the Clojure transaction implementation - and am trying to understand the model behind it.

I'm reading through [a description of a Software Transactional Memory in hardware](http://arrdem.com/drafts/transactions.html) implementation, and it prompted me to think there must be 'categories' of transactional model.

My question is: **What category of Transactional Model does the Clojure STM fall into?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Mark Volkmann's article about Clojure's STM](http://java.ociweb.com/mark/stm/article.html) is an amazing source of information on the subject – I highly recommend that you give it a read if you're interested in the topic, whether you're after a high-level design overview or a description of low-level implementation details.

To summarize, Clojure's STM's transaction model is based on MVCC and snapshot isolation. It has certain peculiar features (for example [the way in which it interacts with threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2841750/how-do-nested-dosync-calls-behave/2842270#2842270)), but on the whole this description should give you the right idea.